# CSS: how to refer to second child class of a div

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

My html code is like.

```
<div id="slider-range" class="ui-slider">
    <div class="ui-slider-range" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle" style="left: 0%;"></a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle" style="left: 100%;"></a>
</div>
```

I only want to give `<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle" style="left: 0%;"></a>` a style for it, but not for `<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle" style="left: 100%;"></a>`. Because I used JQuery UI to generate the code, there is no way for me to add another class. I don't think I can use "ui-slider-handle:last-child", because IE 7 does not support it. How do I do it? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have jQueryUI, I assume you have jQuery, so you could go with

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').eq(0).addClass('my_beautiful_css_class')
```

`.eq(x)` gives you the `x+1`th element in the array of results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
$('a.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').addClass('className')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use nth-child, but I'm not sure if works for IE 7.
I really recommend you to abandon IE 8 and above.

Sample:

```
.ui-slider-range:nth-child(2n+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use first-of-type:

```
#slider-range a:first-of-type {}
```